# JMeter create response variable

Tags: jmeter

How can I create variable from a response data?
I want to create variable **n1** which will get the value from variable **v1**, because **v1** is dynamic variable.

Response part:

```
q=q.replace("v1=2780");
```

Comment: This should be tagged as "Jmeter", not "javascript" and "meter"

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify your question a little?  is "v1" a JMETER variable, or a variable in the program you are testing?

It sounds like you want to use a regular expression to extract the value of v1 and save the results as jmeter variable n1.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Comment: v1 is variable in response data of JMeter (or embeded javascript response). And n1 will be JMeter variable which will get value from v1.

Comment: Use a regex.  I would recommend downloading "the Regex Coach" to help write your regular expression.  It uses PERL, and this site is a fantastic resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/